# How to extract properties from 'data' key property from interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
export interface ISubjectData {
  goal: IGoal,
  subjects: ISubject[]
}

export interface IChapterData {
  subject: ISubject
  chapters: IChapter[]
}

export interface ISubjectChapterData {
  type: string,
  data: ISubjectData | IChapterData
}
```

How to extract `data.subjects` from above interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I think you have to cast the `data` property to `IChapterData`. I think it should look like this `(chapter.data as IChapterData).subject`.

Comment: In addition to @JanMares comment, use a type guard for type-safety as well.